# TKinter read csv file display all datas in table format add button for each row

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am new into python TKInter
my specfication is like want to read CSV file and display all the datas
for every row need to add one button , when button is clicked ,corresponding emprecord open
in other popupwindow

my code is below. Here where I need to add button
ANy help is highly useful for me

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import csv
 
root = Tk()
root.title("Python Read CSV FILE")
width = 500
height = 400
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0) 
TableMargin = Frame(root, width=500)
TableMargin.pack(side=TOP)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=VERTICAL)
tree = ttk.Treeview(TableMargin, columns=("empId", "name", "Address"), height=400, selectmode="extended", yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
tree.heading('empId', text="empId", anchor=W)
tree.heading('name', text="name", anchor=W)
tree.heading('Address', text="Address", anchor=W)
tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=300)
tree.pack()
 
with open('emp.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        empId = row['empId']
        name = row['name']
        address = row['Address']
        tree.insert("", 0, values=(empId, name, address))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to have a button for each record.  Just one button below the treeview is enough.

Comment: my requirement is like ,for each row we need to display a button

Comment: Basically you cannot add a button to a row in treeview.